# Pass json String into a Model in Django

Tags: json, django, django-models

I am new to Django so please bear with me if my question sounds trivial. I have an item_json string which I am able to pass into a model in Django. However, what I would really want to do is parse the json string and pass the elements of the string into different fields in my model. Please let me know how to do this.

```
My json string looks like this:
{
"pr5":
[2,"<b>Product Item</b>",13,15]
}
```

where pr5 represents the product id, 2 represents the items purchased, Product Item represents the name of the product, 13 represents the stock remaining and 15 represents the price.

My model looks like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    items_json = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places=2, 
                                                           default= 0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 90)
    mob = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    apartment = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use route to pass data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ...

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{"pr5":[2,"<b>Product Item</b>",13,15] }'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["pr5"][0])
print(y["pr5"][1])
print(y["pr5"][2])
print(y["pr5"][1].split('<b>')[1].split('</b>')[0])
print(y["pr5"][3])
```

Comment: Thanks!! This helped.